# Generating color for mesh in Texture3D or shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, performance

In Unity, I'm trying to choose between two ways of procedurally colorizing meshes (with vertex color). The main concern here is performance, knowing that my software is already GPU bound (more specifically on the memory bandwidth side)

- First option: Generate the color in the fragment shader. The advantage here is that there is no memory transfert needed. The disadvantages are that the procedural generation of a color implies a pretty complex "algorithm" with branching(ifs) and noise and I'm worried that doing this calculation for every pixel is going to be really slow.
- Second option: Generate all the colors in C#, store them in a 3DTexture and read it in the shader to assign color to each pixel. The disadvantage here is that if the texture is sent to the GPU every frame, that will obviously not help with my memory bandwidth problem... It depends on a thing that I'm not sure about, is the texture stored in the GPU (if I dont change it of course), or does Unity sends it back at every frame, or for each GameObjects?

Which one would you choose?
Do you see some other thing I should take into account?

Comment: Procedural textures through the fragment shader makes sense. Second option sounds really weird for me. Well, you know, you actually answered yourself in your question.

Comment: We'll be able to give more detailed & evidence-based answers if you share the actual colour generation method you're using, and profiling results that show where it's currently pushing your budgets. Depending on these specifics, we might even be able to find hybrids, like "pre-generate this part, then do that part per fragment"